# how to cancel the action in redux saga before the takeLatest api is called when a certain condition is not met

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have created an event handler where the form gets submitted when the user clicks a submit button:

```
 export function* rootSaga(){
 yield [ 
  watchSubmittingForm()]}
 }

 export function watchSubmittingForm(){
 const state = yield select();
 let email = state.form.email;
 let password = state.form.password; 

  yield* takeLatest("SUBMIT_LOGIN", addLogin, email, password)
 }
```

How do i make it not run the addLogin call when the email or password is null in redux way?

In jquery way, we have something called, event.prevenDefault(), here what is the saga way to not run the takeLatest API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The takeLatest helper is going to fire on the latest "SUBMIT_LOGIN" action. So I would wrap the action creator or code that fires off the action in a conditional. Something like

```
if (email && password) dispatch(submitLogin());
```

That way you aren't passing the action through the redux pipeline, and the middleware won't see it, if you do have a password and email, the action will be dispatched and the saga middleware will intercept it.

Comment: after reading the doc, i saw that it worked better if i had used yield take not yield takeLatest.